How to use gcc compiler on Github windows runners when using scikit-build-core
I'm using scikit-build-core to build my c++ program on github windows runners. I would like to use gcc instead of microsoft visual studio as the compiler. Below is how I configure compiler settings in my program, but it does not work (see the log, MSVS was used)
Github workflow file
name: build-wheels

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, release]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build_wheels:
    name: Build wheel for ${{ matrix.buildplat[1] }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.buildplat[0] }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        buildplat:
          - [windows-2022, win_amd64]
        python: ["cp38"]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build wheels for win
        if: ${{ contains(matrix.buildplat[1], 'win') }}
        uses: pypa/cibuildwheel@v2.19
        env:
          CIBW_BUILD: ${{ matrix.python }}-${{ matrix.buildplat[1] }}
          CIBW_ENVIRONMENT_WINDOWS: >
            CC=gcc
            CXX=g++
            SKBUILD_CMAKE_ARGS="-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc;-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++"

      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          path: ./wheelhouse/*.whl

pyproject.toml file
[project.urls]
"Source Code" = "https://github.com/jiawlu/OSM2GMNS"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/jiawlu/OSM2GMNS/issues"

[build-system]
requires = ["scikit-build-core>=0.9.0", "ninja>=1.0"]
build-backend = "scikit_build_core.build"

[project]
name = "osm2gmns"
version = "1.0.0dev1"

requires-python = ">=3.8"
dependencies = []

classifiers = [
  "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 or later (GPLv3+)",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11",
  "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.12",
]


[tool.scikit-build]
wheel.packages = ["osm2gmns"]
wheel.install-dir = "osm2gmns"
wheel.expand-macos-universal-tags = true

cmake.version = ">=3.25"
cmake.args = ["-DBUILD_OSM2GMNS_EXE=OFF","-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc","-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++","-GNinja"]
cmake.build-type = "Release"
cmake.verbose = true

sdist.include = [
    "docs",
    "python",
    "src"
]

sdist.exclude = [
  ".github",
  ".gitattributes",
  ".gitignore",
  "build"
]

[tool.cibuildwheel]
build = "*"
skip = "cp3{6,7}-*"


CMake generator "Visual Studio" doesn't allow to change a compiler. You could use other generator, which can be customized with the compiler. E.g. "MinGW Makefiles" one.
